# Amount of data written on a partition

Tags: ext4, partitioning

Is there any way to find out how much data have been written on the partition since it was created?

Talking about ext4 fs.

Comment: As in, how much free and used space is on the partition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the files in `/sys/fs/ext4/<dev-name>/`.
You would be interested in `/sys/fs/ext4/<dev-name>/lifetime_write_kbytes`.

> lifetime_write_kbytes
>
> This file is read-only and shows the number
>   of kilobytes of data that have been written to this filesystem since
>   it was created.

*hth*

[EXT4 Kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt)

Answer (score 0):

If supported by the drive we can read the number of LBAs written during a drive's lifetime from it's [S.M.A.R.T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) data with **[smartclt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/smartctl.8.html)** (from [smartmontools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/smartmontools) [image: Install smartmontools]):

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdX
```

Replace `sdX` with the drive you want to read.

The entry `241 Total LBAs Written` displays the total count of LBAs written during the device's lifetime. For an SSD we can also read the estimated time left from `231 SSD Life Left`.

This will however read data for the **whole drive**, not a partition. If only a partition matters go for the [answer already given](https://askubuntu.com/a/299036/3940).

Comment: s/smartclt/smartctl/g.  I'd fix it myself but "edits must be at least 6 characters."  sigh.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean how much space is used/free on each partition, simply open a terminal (ctrl-alt-T) and type `df`. Alternatively you can use `df -h` to shorten gigabytes, megabytes etc. This will show you the usage (in bytes and percentage) of all mounted partitions, regardless of the file system each is formatted to.

Comment: Did you read his question?

Comment: @blujay Yes, and this is how I interpreted what was being asked (hence "if this is what you meant"). It had never occurred to me that it might be possible to get a cumulative total as mentioned in the other answers, so this seemed like it could have been what he was asking (see also someone else's [unanswered] comment on the OP)